# Display a .raw image in ASP.NET 2010 WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a web application, and i have to show an image in a popup page but the image extension is ".raw", i try to set the imageurl to an image control of asp.net or to a img tab of HTML but it doesn't works. It's a 32 bit image and the size is 1920 x 1080, and the platform that i am using is asp.net 2010 webforms with C#.

How can i render a .raw image to be displayed on a asp.net web application?

Comment: Is this a raw image from a digital camera?  If it is then you can't do this.  Pretty much every camera has their own proprietary format which the browser won't be able to render.

Comment: no, the image is created by a dll that was created in c++

Comment: i have a dll that take another file with a special extension and create the .raw file to be Displayed on the web application

Comment: At the end of the day, what images you can display on the **web** are the types of images that browsers support (e.g. jpg, gif, png, svg).That said, you'll have to find some SDK/utility that will handle the conversion from raw to any of the "web formats".

Answer (score 0):

Since .raw files are not supported by browsers (unless some addon/plugin/extension can handle it) the browser does not know what to do with it.

What you can do is create an `IHttpHandler` that will handle this extension (you map it in web.config). In the code behind, the handler will find the .raw file, encode it in some other popular format like .jpeg (and probably persist it to disk so as to not re-encode everytime you want to access the .jpeg equivalent) and output that to the browser.

Since .raw is a generic format that just means that the file is in the format as created by the imaging device, finding the proper tool for the conversion may or may not be easy. I would start by trying `ImageMagick` and `dcraw`.

Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format for more reading.